# VB.NET How does one read a textbox into a string and use the string for something else?

Tags: vb.net

I have two text boxes on my form. Textbox1 and Textbox2. Textbox1 will contain information. I want to code my button to read textbox 1 and put it into a string or some way for the app to read the textbox and store the information into it's memory.

Then I want to be able to read that string into the second part of my application.

Not sure where to go with this. Should I:

1. read the textbox into a string using a streamreader and then use a streamwriter to write the data into a string?
2. save the textbox to a .txt file then use the openfiledialog to read the text file into a string to use?

Any help guys would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just use the `.Text` property of the TextBox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In older VB dialects like Access VBA there was the concept of default properties that were automatically accessed when you wrote something like this:

```vb
s = Me!txtMyTextBox
```

Behind the scenes VBA did automatically something like this:

```vb
s = Me!txtMyTextBox.Value
```

In VB.NET if you write `Dim t = Textbox1` then `t` will by typed as `TextBox` and contain a reference to the textbox. To retrieve the text from the textbox, access its `Text` property explicitly:

```
Dim s as String
s = Textbox1.Text;
```

It depends where you want to use the string later. If you want to use it outside of the form you have two possibilities: Either let the form export the string or get the string from your form from outside.

## 1 Export the text

In a Module (let us call it MyModule) define a public string:

```
Public TheText as String
```

In the form:

```
MyModule.TheText = Textbox1.Text;
```

The text is now available globally in your whole application.

---

## 2 Get it from outside

In the form, wrap the Textbox text in a property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property TheText() As String
    Get
        Return Textbox1.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

Somewhere else, assuming that the form is your main form and is called `frmMain`:

```
Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(Application.OpenForms(0), frmMain).TheText)
```

Or if you have a form variable strongly typed as your specific form, e.g. `Dim frm As frmMain` (and not just as `Form`):

```
Console.WriteLine(frm.TheText)
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve text from a textbox, you can use the `TextBox.Text` property and store that value into a String. To save that String to a file, you can use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(string filename, string content)`.

There are many ways to store a String for use. This is simply a simple (not always *best*) way of storing a string to a file.

Comment: cool thanks..what if instead of saving the textbox1 text to file I wanted to call it into another process that will do something with that string? I am using the text from textbox 1 (which is an XML file) to pull into my second part of my app that will parse the xml file to extract nodes. This is my code to get the string from textbox1 but it never gets the string.         

Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
xmlDoc.LoadXml(textbox1.text)

Comment: What error do you get? The LoadXml method takes the actual contents of the XML file, not the file name, so if that is what the textbox contains it should work.

Comment: Here is an example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx#Y200