# How can I retrieve data from a textbox in Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a simple username and password login form on visual basic. this works perfectly. but what I would like to know is there any way I could retrieve the usernames and passwords entered and save them as a string or anything similar?

Comment: `Dim uname = TxtUserName.Text` and `Dim pwd = TxtPassWord.Text`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET How does one read a textbox into a string and use the string for something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627186/vb-net-how-does-one-read-a-textbox-into-a-string-and-use-the-string-for-somethin)

Comment: Please edit your question tags to remove C# and add VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have two different textboxes for the username and password so you would do:

```
Dim UserName as String
Dim Password as String
```

The textboxes each have a different name so you do:

```
UserName = NameOfYourTextbox1.text
Password = NameOfYourTextbox2.text
```

Comment: @DeclanTiff This is the better answer, but if you want to store more than one password, you'll need to look into two dimensional arrays or data tables and also find out how to save them. It would be beyond the scope of an answer here to provide all(there's a lot) this info.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe even something like this:

```
List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
userNames.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

You might also be able to save them in a text-file using streamreaders and streamwriters.